# how to remove last zero from number in matlab

Tags: matlab, zero, trailing

If I set a variable in Matlab, say var1 = 2.111, after running the script, Matlab returns var1 = 2.1110. I want Matlab to return the original number, with no trailing zero. Anyone know how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default Matlab displays results in Short fixed decimal format, with 4 digits after the decimal point.
You can change that to various other format such as:

**long** 
 
Long fixed decimal format, with 15 digits after the decimal point for double values, and 7 digits after the decimal point for single values.
3.141592653589793

**shortE** 
 
Short scientific notation, with 4 digits after the decimal point.
Integer-valued floating-point numbers with a maximum of 9 digits do not display in scientific notation.
3.1416e+00

**longE** 
 
Long scientific notation, with 15 digits after the decimal point for double values, and 7 digits after the decimal point for single values.
Integer-valued floating-point numbers with a maximum of 9 digits do not display in scientific notation.
3.141592653589793e+00

**shortG** 
 
The more compact of short fixed decimal or scientific notation, with 5 digits.
3.1416

**longG** 
 
The more compact of long fixed decimal or scientific notation, with 15 digits for double values, and 7 digits for single values.
3.14159265358979

**shortEng** 
 
Short engineering notation, with 4 digits after the decimal point, and an exponent that is a multiple of 3.
3.1416e+000

**longEng** 
 
Long engineering notation, with 15 significant digits, and an exponent that is a multiple of 3.
3.14159265358979e+000

However I don't think other options are available. If you absolutely want to remove those zeros you would have to cast you result in a string and remove the trailing 0 characters and then display your result as a string and not a number.